# How to remove 0 from array of arrays python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays and I want to remove all the value that are zeros.
I have this

```
M_data = [
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [19, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [27, 31, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [8, 18, 26, 0.0, 0.0],
    [33, 36, 41, 31, 0.0],
    [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]
    ]
```

and I want to remove all the zeros, so I get

```
M_data = [
    [],
    [19],
    [27, 31],
    [8, 18, 26],
    [33, 36, 41, 31],
    [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]
    ]
```

How can I do this? (python)

Comment: any help with list.remove(x)?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
M_data = [
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [19, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [27, 31, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [8, 18, 26, 0.0, 0.0],
    [33, 36, 41, 31, 0.0],
    [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]
    ]

result = [[e for e in lst if e] for lst in M_data]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[], [19], [27, 31], [8, 18, 26], [33, 36, 41, 31], [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]]
```

The above is *equivalent* to:

```
result = []
for lst in M_data:
    inner = []
    for e in lst:
        if e:
            inner.append(e)
    result.append(inner)
```

The idea is to iter over the inner lists and create new list with only elements different of `0`. To check for values distinct that 0 you can use the value directly an `if` statement in Python 0 is `False`. For example `if e` is equivalent to `if e != 0`, when `e` is number.

Comment: Explain your one liner too.

Comment: @DanielMesejo just curious, how this is checking if its zero(0) or not to append to new list? I did run your code. Its working fine, but just didnt understand

Comment: Using `if e:` in Python 0 is False, so you can use the value directly in an if statement. I updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) on each list in `M_data`:

```
filtered = [list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, l)) for l in M_data]
print(filtered)
# [[], [19], [27, 31], [8, 18, 26], [33, 36, 41, 31], [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` to filter all the `None` (0) values as

```
lst = [list(filter(None, lst)) for lst in M_data]
```

**Output**

```
[[], [19], [27, 31], [8, 18, 26], [33, 36, 41, 31], [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]]
```

The `list` converts the output of the `filter` command back to a list since you want an empty list too. You loop over the sublists of your `M_data` and then filter out the 0's. This one liner is also called *list comprehension*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter the list:

```
M_data = [
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [19, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [27, 31, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [8, 18, 26, 0.0, 0.0],
    [33, 36, 41, 31, 0.0],
    [18, 1, 32, 17, 35]
    ]
M_data = [[x for x in y if x != 0] for y in L]
M_data
```

[image]